# Translate box shadow into react native native shadow

Tags: android, css, ios, react-native

I have the following css design

```
box-shadow:  0px 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
```

and i want to translate it to react native
the code is the following

```
shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 3 },
shadowOpacity: 0.28,
shadowRadius: 12,
elevation: 12,
```

but the result is not the same as per design

I also noticed that that there is not a 1-1 analogy on offset and radius according to [react-native-shadow-generator](https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/)

Is there any specific formula or i should adjust it visually?

Comment: have you figure this out?

Comment: @chenop wondering the same. Has anyone figured this out?

Comment: @BrianM.Wachira didnt figure this out - common problem I still encounter from time to time...